# Convert a decimal to the smallest possible numeric type without any data loss

Tags: c#, .net

I want to write a method which converts a `decimal` to the smallest possible numeric type without any data loss.  For examples:

- `Convert(1)` should return a `byte`
- `Convert(257)` should return a `short`
- `Convert(1.1)` should return a `float`
- and so on

The input of the method is always a `decimal` and the output is any of the following .NET numeric types: `sbyte`, `byte`, `short`, `ushort`, `int`, `uint`, `long`, `ulong`, `float`, `double`, and `decimal`.

I have tried using `checked()` to catch the `OverflowException`, however that approach doesn't prevent loss.  For example, `checked((int)1.1)` won't throw any exception and return `1`!  Therefore, it's not what I want.

Any recommendation?

**Update:** expected method signature

```
public object Convert(decimal d)
{
   // return ...
}
```

Comment: I have teh codez - I'll show you if you give me the signature of that method.

Comment: I think what @Ingo means is: How would you use a method like that?

Comment: @Buu: Please add a usage scenario with a few lines of code.

Comment: @Henk: I've added the signature

Comment: @Buu: the result could only be used with reflection and/or an ugly cascading `if/else`. Not much gain to be seen.

Comment: @Ingo, @Henk: it's hard to explain why I need such a method.  I'm writing a programming language interop'ing with .NET; let's say some past decisions lead me to need this method as I implement the interop layer :).

Comment: @Henk: that's exactly what I need though.  Let's say my language invoke .NET code like this, dotNetObj.acceptByte(24) and it happens that all numeric values in my language are decimal (so that 24 is decimal as far as the interpreter knows).  The conversion method will help the interpreter make better decision on which overload (if any) to invoke.

Comment: Well, stecya seems to have an answer without exceptions. I think you still need specs for signed/unsigned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try to use TryParse

```
        short res;
        decimal value = 8913798132;
        bool s = short.TryParse(value.ToString(), out res); // returns false
```

Comment: And if it succeeds you try byte/sbyte

Comment: He can try byte/sbyte first. From smaller to larger

Comment: or start in the middle and do a kind of binary search.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I end up doing.  Some reflection could be used to reduce the amount of code -- but since this method is called so many times in my app that I feel better this way.

```
private static object NarrowNumber(decimal value)
{
    decimal wholePart = Math.Truncate(value);
    if (value == wholePart)
    {
        if (sbyte.MinValue <= wholePart && wholePart <= sbyte.MaxValue)
            return (sbyte)wholePart;
        if (byte.MinValue <= wholePart && wholePart <= byte.MaxValue)
            return (byte)wholePart;
        if (short.MinValue <= wholePart && wholePart <= short.MaxValue)
            return (short)wholePart;
        if (ushort.MinValue <= wholePart && wholePart <= ushort.MaxValue)
            return (ushort)wholePart;
        if (int.MinValue <= wholePart && wholePart <= int.MaxValue)
            return (int)wholePart;
        if (uint.MinValue <= wholePart && wholePart <= uint.MaxValue)
            return (uint)wholePart;
        if (long.MinValue <= wholePart && wholePart <= long.MaxValue)
            return (long)wholePart;
        if (ulong.MinValue <= wholePart && wholePart <= ulong.MaxValue)
            return (ulong)wholePart;
    }
    else
    {
        var strValue = value.ToString();
        float f;
        if (float.TryParse(strValue, out f))
            return f;
        double d;
        if (double.TryParse(strValue, out d))
            return d;
    }
    return value;
}
```

Comment: That's exactly how I would I've done it, would I ever need such a method.